# tkinter: binding mousewheel to scrollbar in several canvas in several frames

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a GUI with several frames. I've tried to add a MouseWheel event into canvas in different frames. If I use .bind() in PageOne it works fine. If i'm using it a second time it does nothing in both frames.
Actually I think it's  easy to solve it, but after hours looking for answers I still didn't get it.
Has anyone an idea for me?
Thanks a lot.

My code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.shared_data = {
            "var1": tk.StringVar(),
        }

        self.title('Mousewheel Scroll')
        self.iconbitmap('')
        self.geometry('500x500')

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font="Arial 15")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        btn1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        btn2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        btn1.pack()
        btn2.pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        # Create a Main Frame
        self.main_frame_p1 = tk.Frame(self)
        self.main_frame_p1.pack(side="bottom")  # fill="both", expand=1

        # Create a Canvas
        self.canvas_p1 = tk.Canvas(self)
        # Add a Scrollbar to Canvas
        self.scrollbar_y = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas_p1.yview)
        self.scrollbar_y.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.scrollbar_x = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas_p1.xview)
        self.scrollbar_x.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        self.canvas_p1.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.scrollbar_y.config(command=self.canvas_p1.yview)
        self.scrollbar_x.config(command=self.canvas_p1.xview)

        # Configure the Canvas
        self.canvas_p1.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_y.set)
        self.canvas_p1.configure(xscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_x.set)

        self.canvas_p1.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.canvas_p1.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas_p1.bbox("all")))
        self.canvas_p1.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", lambda e: self.on_mousewheel)

        # Another Frame inside Canvas
        self.in_canvas_frame_p1 = tk.Frame(self.canvas_p1)
        # Add that Frame to a Window in the Canvas
        self.canvas_p1.create_window((0, 0), window=self.in_canvas_frame_p1, anchor="nw")

        label1 = tk.Label(self.canvas_p1, text="This is page one", font="Arial 15")
        label1.pack()

        button1 = tk.Button(self.canvas_p1, text="Go to Start Page", command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button1.pack()
        button1_1 = tk.Button(self.canvas_p1, text="Go to Page Two", command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button1_1.pack()

        self.canvas_p1.create_line(0, 0, 400, 700, fill='red')

    def on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas_p1.yview_scroll((-1 * (event.delta // 120)), "units")

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        # Create a Main Frame
        self.main_frame_p1 = tk.Frame(self)
        self.main_frame_p1.pack(side="bottom")  # fill="both", expand=1

        # Create a Canvas
        self.canvas_p2 = tk.Canvas(self)
        # Add a Scrollbar to Canvas
        self.scrollbar_y = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas_p2.yview)
        self.scrollbar_y.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.scrollbar_x = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas_p2.xview)
        self.scrollbar_x.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        self.canvas_p2.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.scrollbar_y.config(command=self.canvas_p2.yview)
        self.scrollbar_x.config(command=self.canvas_p2.xview)

        # Configure the Canvas
        self.canvas_p2.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_y.set)
        self.canvas_p2.configure(xscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_x.set)

        self.canvas_p2.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.canvas_p2.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas_p2.bbox("all")))
        self.canvas_p2.bind("<MouseWheel>", lambda e: self.on_mousewheel)

        # Another Frame inside Canvas
        self.in_canvas_frame_p2 = tk.Frame(self.canvas_p2)
        # Add that Frame to a Window in the Canvas
        self.canvas_p2.create_window((0, 0), window=self.in_canvas_frame_p2, anchor="nw")

        label2 = tk.Label(self.canvas_p2, text="This is page two", font="Arial 15")
        label2.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self.canvas_p2, text="Go to Start Page", command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button2.pack()
        button2_1 = tk.Button(self.canvas_p2, text="Go to Page One", command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2_1.pack()

        self.canvas_p2.create_line(0, 0, 200, 700, fill='red')

    def on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas_p2.yview_scroll((-1 * (event.delta // 120)), "units")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to this statement (in both `p1` and `p2`)

```py
self.canvas_p1.bind("<MouseWheel>", lambda e: self.on_mousewheel)
```

The problem is that the function is not being called, since you are using `lambda`, in order to call it you would have to use `self.on_mousewheel(e)` (you can not use `self.on_mousewheel()` as the event parameter `e` will be passed to the `lambda` function, but not the `self.on_mousewheel` function and you'll end up with an error)

Changing it to this should fix it

```py
self.canvas_p1.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", lambda e: self.on_mousewheel(e))
```

Now, since you are not providing any additional parameter than the event, you can as well use the following (you don't have to use the `lambda` function since, the event is passed as a default positional argument to the function)

```py
self.canvas_p1.bind_all("<MouseWheel>",self.on_mousewheel)
```

Comment: @Stefanie You can remove it and accept this as the correct answer.